# How session is managed in magento system?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, session, data

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

I tried the above code in root of the magento system but it fails to list all the session variables. It returns null.

Then how the magento stores all the session values?

Does it use $_SESSION super global or it follows some other way to store session?

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses its own models to handle sessions such as:

- `Mage_Core_Model_Session`
- `Mage_Customer_Model_Session`
- `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session`

The low level class that handles the `session_start` is `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien`

Native Magento handles automatically the session start thus you shouldn't have to call `session_start` in your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use magento session outside of magento such as

```
          <?php

           echo getcwd();

           define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd()); 

           $mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';

           require_once $mageFilename;

           Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');

           // access the magento session outside


                 $customerSession = Mage::getModel('customer/session');

                 print_r($customerSession);

                 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
                echo $_product->getName();
             ?>
```